# gluPerspective equivalent for Qt and openGL

Tags: c++, linux, qt, opengl

I'm trying to get Qt and openGL working together so that I can do away with glu and glut.

I have everything working like I want it, except for my perspective matrix.

I'm only painting a simple 3D cube and want my viewpoint to be at an angle.

I've tried coding a replacement for gluPerspective, but I can't get what I want.

Thus, how can I get a perspective matrix working correctly?

Note: I am open to other alternatives, as I'm still trying to get used to openGL and Qt, and how to properly use these two frameworks.

Below is my implementation to my GLWidget class:

```
GLWidget::GLWidget(QWidget *parent) : QGLWidget(parent) {
    setMouseTracking(true);
}

void GLWidget::initializeGL() {
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}

void GLWidget::resizeGL(int w, int h) {
    glViewport(0,0,w,h);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-30.0, 30.0, -30.0, 30.0, -30.0, 30.0);

    GLdouble aspect = w / (h ? h : 1);

    const GLdouble zNear = -30.0, zFar = 30.0, fov = 30.0;

    perspective(fov, aspect, zNear, zFar);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

void GLWidget::paintGL() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glVertex3iv(a);
    glVertex3iv(b);
    glVertex3iv(c);
    glVertex3iv(d);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glVertex3iv(a);
    glVertex3iv(e);
    glVertex3iv(f);
    glVertex3iv(b);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glVertex3iv(d);
    glVertex3iv(h);
    glVertex3iv(g);
    glVertex3iv(c);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glVertex3iv(e);
    glVertex3iv(f);
    glVertex3iv(g);
    glVertex3iv(h);
    glEnd();

}

void GLWidget::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* event) {
    switch(event->key()) {
    case Qt::Key_Escape:
        close();
        break;
    default:
        event->ignore();
        break;
    }
}

void GLWidget::perspective(GLdouble fovy, GLdouble aspect, GLdouble zNear, GLdouble zFar)
{
    GLdouble xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax;

    ymax = zNear * tan( fovy * M_PI / 360.0 );
    ymin = -ymax;
    xmin = ymin * aspect;
    xmax = ymax * aspect;

    glFrustum( xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, zNear, zFar );
}
```

Comment: Why can't you keep using glu?

Comment: @AndreasHaferburg: Maybe OP is aiming to abandon the fixed function pipeline in the long term.

Answer (score 4):

Your perspective function is correct (in the sense that it does the same as gluPerspective() did). But you should be aware that 
in resizeGL(), you are using both Ortho and Frustum, so you end up with a projection matrix Ortho*Persepctive, which basically adds some scaling and translation after the perspective distortion is applied.

Comment: Good point, I was testing with just my perspective matrix, but when I just use my perspective matrix, I get nothing but a black screen, where as the Ortho matrix gives me visibility of my cube. Would returning a matrix from my perspective function and then using glLoadMatrixd(...) solve this problem?

Comment: @Pete: As Andreas Haferburg wrote in his answer, your current fNear value is invalid, so it is no surprise that you do not get a useful output. You do not need to manually load the matrix, it is enough to LoadIdentity before you call your perspective function.

Answer (score 3):

You can either reimplement gluPerspective using glFrustum, or you're doing the future proof thing and use a matrix math library like GLM, Eigen or linmath.h, calculate the matrix using that and load it precalculated into OpenGL using glLoadMatrix or glUniform.

Answer (score 3):

Both fNear and fFar arguments to `glFrustum` have to be positive.